# Is there some way put boxes around matrix elements without too much effort?

Tags: matrices, highlighting

I know this question has been asked before but the examples that they give are too complicated to replicate, [for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376776/draw-a-box-around-selected-entries-of-array?rq=1).

Is there some way to make boxes like these (dashes are not necessary but preferable):

[image]

for entries of a matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is TikZ proposal using `fit`. I've wrapped the code in a command I've called `mymatrixbox`. It takes 4 inputs which define the boundaries of the box using the cell coordinates (it also takes 1 optional input which allows you some control over the default style).

The way it works is like this, say you want to draw a box from (1,1) to (3,1), then use `\mymatrixbox{1}{1}{3}{1}`. To draw a box around a single cell then just repeat the cell coordinates - e.g. `\matrixbox{2}{3}{2}{3}`. If I wanted to draw a box around the entire matrix the code for that would be `\mymatrixbox{1}{1}{3}{3}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}
\pgfkeys{tikz/mymatrix/.style={matrix of math nodes,inner sep=0pt,row sep=0em,column sep=0em,nodes={inner sep=6pt}}}

\newcommand*\mymatrixbox[5][]{\node [fit= (m-#2-#3) (m-#4-#5)] [draw=blue,thick,dashed,rounded corners,inner sep=-2pt,#1] {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm]
    \matrix [mymatrix] (m)  
    {
    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    };

\mymatrixbox{1}{1}{3}{1}
\mymatrixbox{3}{2}{3}{3}
\mymatrixbox[red]{2}{3}{2}{3}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution with `pstricks` and a plain `matrix` environment from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, array}
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

 \begin{equation*}
        \begin{postscript}
        \psset{nodesep=5pt, boxsize=0.7em, linearc=.1, framearc=0.2, linestyle=dashed, dash= 4pt 2pt, linecolor=LightBlue}
        \setlength{\arraycolsep}{6pt}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
            \begin{matrix}
                \Rnode{A}{1}& 0 & 0 \\
                0 &1 & \rnode{E}{0} \\
             \Rnode{B}{0}& \Rnode{C}{0} & \Rnode{D}{1}
            \end{matrix}
        \ncbox{A}{B}
        \ncbox{C}{D}
        \fnode[framesize = 0.56 0.50](E){F}
        \end{postscript}
        \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to set the same width to all columns?

Comment: @pzorba75: I didn't notice, but you're right: there's a width problem and *a priori* I don't see why (normally postscript code is dimensionless, so it doesn't modify the column widths).  If I find a solution, I'll post a new code and warn you.

Comment: @pzorba: Problem solved: it came from incorporating postcript code directly in the matrix (for the frame in the second row) instead of writing code outside. I think now it's OK. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: a slightly modified version of [Milo's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445703/121799) which works with arbitrary matrices, i.e. has that flexibility of [Bernhards nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445742/121799) without having to go through the usual "how do I compile documents containing pstricks and can I be sure that the outcome does not depend on the compiler?" questions. That is, you do not have to write the matrix as a `tikzpicture`. The price you have to pay is that you have to "mark" the elements you want to box with `\tikznode` beforehand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\tikzset{box around/.style={
    draw,rounded corners,
    inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,
    node contents={},fit=#1
},      
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \mathbbm{1}_3=\begin{pmatrix} 
 \tikznode{m-1-1}{1} & 0 & 0\\ 
 \tikznode{m-2-1}{0} & 1 &   \tikznode{m-2-3}{0}\\ 
 \tikznode{m-3-1}{0} & \tikznode{m-3-2}{0} &   \tikznode{m-3-3}{1}
 \end{pmatrix}\;.
\end{equation}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\node[blue,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1.25pt, thick,box around=(m-1-1)(m-3-1)];
\node[red,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1.25pt, thick,box around=(m-2-3)];
\node[purple,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1.25pt, thick,box around=(m-3-2)(m-3-3)];}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could also wrap this into a macro, i.e. the following yields the same output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\tikzset{box around/.style={
    draw,rounded corners,
    inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,
    node contents={},fit=#1
},      
}
\newcommand{\BoxAround}[2][]{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\node[blue,dash pattern=on 2pt off 1.25pt,thick,#1,box around=#2];}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \mathbbm{1}_3=\begin{pmatrix} 
 \tikznode{m-1-1}{1} & 0 & 0\\ 
 \tikznode{m-2-1}{0} & 1 &   \tikznode{m-2-3}{0}\\ 
 \tikznode{m-3-1}{0} & \tikznode{m-3-2}{0} &   \tikznode{m-3-3}{1}
 \end{pmatrix}\;.
\end{equation}
\BoxAround{(m-1-1)(m-3-1)}
\BoxAround[red]{(m-2-3)}
\BoxAround[purple]{(m-3-2)(m-3-3)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

today i discover interesting package `nicematrix`. with it you can write:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{I}_3 = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[columns-width = 1em]
   [code-after= {\begin{tikzpicture}[FIT/.style = {%
                                     draw, semithick, rounded corners, densely dashed,
                                     inner sep=2pt,  fit=#1, node contents={}}
                                    ]
                 \node[FIT=(1-1) (3-1),blue];
                 \node[FIT=(3-2) (3-3),blue];
                 \node[FIT=(1-3) (2-3),red];
                 \end{tikzpicture}
                 }
   ]
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

for correct result you need to compile document at least twice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every path/.append style = { draw, dashed, rounded corners } }

$\mathbf{I}_3 = \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin=2pt]
\Block[tikz={offset=1pt,blue}]{3-1}{} 1 & 0 & 
\Block[tikz={offset=1pt,red}]{2-1}{} 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \Block[tikz={offset=1pt,blue}]{1-2}{} 0 & 1 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]